# C# MySQL DataRow with multiple values

Tags: c#, mysql

Is there a way to do a c# datarow like the below code in a SELECT * query

```
//Have results like blow
string username = (string)row["username"];
```

I've tried but all I seem to see is reader or something, witch I know nothing about and don't understand. Can you lead me to some code that will help or give me a example?

Comment: If you need to perform a query on your database you need to open a SqlConnection, create a SqlCommand,  and use a SqlDataReader to read the result from your query. Is that all you are trying to do?

Comment: Don't be afraid to show what you tried. It makes it easier to see where we need to extend your current solution.

Comment: I have not tryed anything get. I am just trying to get the id from the username so SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "' if you get my drift? and make the result into a string or just get the result..

Answer (score 1):

DataReader is actually exactly what you need. The 'DataRow' class by itself won't help you; that gets used as part of a more complex solution, the 'DataSet' class (which uses 'DataTable' and that in turn uses 'DataColumn' and 'DataRow'). I don't see many people using 'DataSet'; if you want something complex with drag-and-drop design, you should look at using Entity Framework.

Here is a standard way to read values from SQL in .NET via DataReader (which, no matter what anyone says, is the fastest way to simply read data from a SQL database in .NET):

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("<Your connection string here>")
{
    var command = new SqlCommand(
      "SELECT username, email FROM users;",
      connection);
    connection.Open();

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // Using the DataReader (specifically, the SqlDataReader)

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User {0} has email {1}", reader["username"],
                reader["email"]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

[MSDN documentation for DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Most of the code isnt working, And isnt really what im looking for. But thankypu for trying! ill mark it as a userful anser